# How to reference your own class instead of System class?

Tags: vb.net

I have created 2 classes, a Location class and a Main class. I have a shared Location array (named Values) inside my Location class so I could populate a list with its values. In my Main class, I am trying to do:

```
For Each l As Location In Location.Values
   ' Populate List
Next
```

But it says: 'Values' is not a member of 'System.Drawing.Point'

The problem is I have created a class that conflicts with a class that already exists inside System. My question is how do I reference my own Location class instead of the built-in one without renaming my class? Thanks.

Comment: `Location.Values` is an instance, no?  So you have a class and an instance var shadowing a NET Type?  Fewer headaches if you just use a different instance name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the fully qualified type name like:

```
For Each l As WindowsApplication1.Location In WindowsApplication1.Location.Values
```

Just replace `WindowsApplication1` with your root namespace.

---

My project > Application > Root namespace

Comment: I've tried that and it says it's not defined. But, it suggested that I put Global before my root namespace, and it worked. Any idea why?

Comment: It might be that VS suggest to change it to `Global.WindowsApplication1.Location` but `WindowsApplication1.Location` should be just as fine. Or you might need a new rebuild.

Comment: Mhm.. Tried rebuilding and still same issue. I'll just stick with the global before the namespace. Thanks for your help.